# PS Get-MailboxfolderStatistics filter on object

Tags: windows, powershell, command, office365

I would need to pipe a specific result from the command below to a variable that I can use in another command. More specifically, the **`folderpath` field**. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm unfamiliar with the `Where-Object` cmdlet. Can someone give me an example?

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar
```

Gives as result (and more):

```
RunspaceId                        : dsfdsfsdfsf9
Date                              : 24/07/2014 8:41:48
CreationTime                      : 24/07/2014 8:41:48
LastModifiedTime                  : 5/09/2018 12:42:37
Name                              : Kalender
FolderPath                        : /Kalender
FolderId                          : LgAAAADmF+sdfsdfdf/KAAAAAAENAAAC
FolderType                        : Calendar
ContentFolder                     : True
ContentMailboxGuid                : 86afb4sfdsfdsdfsd7
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps

Comment: `(Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar).FolderPath` or `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FolderPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $folderPath = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FolderPath
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the property using one of the following:

```
(Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar).FolderPath
# or
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FolderPath
```

To assign to variable just add the assignment:

```
$folder = (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar).FolderPath
# or
$folder = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FolderPath
```

It might happen that the variable will be an array with more than one object. Then you can access any of them using `$folder[$i]` where `$i` is an index (starting from 0). If you want more universal solution you can force the variable to be array using:

```
[array]$folder = (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar).FolderPath
# or
[array]$folder = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user1 -FolderScope Calendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FolderPath
```